# Example app EmailContacts throws Error - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,

Tags: servicestack

Newbie.  Got EmailContacts from GitHub and opened it up and on VS2013 Premium and complied and ran and I go the following error.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Rockmeister

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 30:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
Line 31:       <assemblies>
Line 32:         <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 33:       </assemblies>
Line 34:       <buildProviders>

Source File: C:\Users\rkumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\EmailContacts.ref\EmailContacts\web.config    Line: 32 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do two things to make it work with VS2013 Premium

(1) Comment out the System.Web.Razor in EmailContacts webconfig file

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
        <!-- Commented out Razor
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>
        -->
```

...

(2) PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
BTW, The current version is 3.1.1

This solved my issue and I can run the app fine.
HTH
rockmeister

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Studio I added the NuGet package for Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (v3.1.1) and it got past this error. (And encountered others.)

Comment: Thanks @Harry.  I has to do two thing to fix my issue.  Don't know how yours worked without the webconfig change.  Anyway, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I think on Windows .Net can kind of _guess_ the right references but with mono it has to be correct. So I found I had to reference it as `System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0`